# Kotlin - Remove repetitive method calls for fragments

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to remove duplicating methods by creating one singular method that takes params. I have a few methods that do the exact thing where they create an instance of a class, a fragment manager and then shows the fragment. Just want to know how I can shorten the following into one method and just pass in params.

```
private fun openAboutDialogue() {
    //get a fragment manager
    val fm = fragmentManager
    val abtDialogue = GetStartedFragment()
    abtDialogue.show(fm, "About the App")
}

private fun openNewRouteDialogue() {
    val confirmNewDialogue = NewRouteFragment()
    val fm = fragmentManager
    confirmNewDialogue.show(fm, "NewRoute")
}

private fun openEndRouteDialogue() {
    val confirmEndDialogue = TrafficDataFragment()
    val fm = fragmentManager
    confirmEndDialogue.show(fm, "GetTraffic")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correcly, you simply create something like the following which takes `Fragment` as an argument:

```
private fun openDialogue(fragment: Fragment, text: String) =
    fragment.show(fragmentManager, text)
```

Comment: Close, I want to be able to call any fragment class and show their fragment. This looks like I still have to create multiple methods

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong variable name in the method, changed it to fragment. I think this method works with any Fragment actually?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could do

```
fun AppCompatActivity.openDialogue(fragment: DialogFragment, tag: String) {
    fragment.show(supportFragmentManager, tag)
}
```

But now you have to call it as

```
openDialogue(GetStartedFragment(), "About the App")
openDialogue(NewRouteFragment(), "NewRoute")
openDialogue(TrafficDataFragment(), "GetTraffic")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy and hide Fragment class from the caller you can use an enum for selection which can double as a fragment tag as well:

```
enum class DialogueType{ GET_STARTED, NEW_ROUTE, TRAFFIC,DATA }

private fun openDialogue(type: DialogueType){
    val fragment = when(type) {
        GET_STARTED -> GetStartedFragment()
        NEW_ROUTE -> NewRouteFragment()
        TRAFFIC_DATA -> TrafficDataFragment()
    } 
    fragment.show(fragmentManager, type.name)
}
```